# Panels take equal space

Tags: java, layout, panel, frame, gridbaglayout

I have two panels. The first one looks like this.

```
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel
{
    public BoardPanel()
    {
         setLayout(null);
         this.setOpaque(false);

        Button button = new JButton("..");
        button.setLocation(...);
        button.setSize(...);
        add(button);
    }

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        /*
        * Painting some stuff here. 
        */
    }   
}
```

The other panel is something like this:

```
public class OtherPanel extends JPanel
{
    public OtherPanel()
    {
        super();
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setOpaque(false);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLocation(...);
        panel1.setSize(...);
        panel1.setOpaque( .. );

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLocation(...);
        panel2.setSize(...);
        panel2.setOpaque( .. );

        add(panel1):
        add(panel2);
    }   

}
```

After that , I put both my panels in a frame. But I want my BoardPanel to occupy more screen than OtherPanel. So I used GridBagLayout for the frame

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{ 
    private GridBagLayout aGridLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    private GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    public MainFrame()
    {
        super("Quoridor");
        setLayout(gridLayout);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1366, 768);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.decode("#b2a6a6"));

        BoardPanel boardPanel = new BoardPanel();
        OtherPanel otherPanel = new OtherPanel();

        this.addComponent(boardPanel, 1, 1, 2, 1);
        this.addComponent(otherPanel, 1, 3, 1, 1);
    }

    public void addComponent(Component component , int row , int column , int width
            , int height)
    {
        constraints.gridx = column;
        constraints.gridy = row;
        constraints.gridwidth = width;
        constraints.gridheight = height;
        aGridLayout.setConstraints(component, constraints);
        add(component);
    }
}
```

The problem is , that the frame gives equal space to both panels , and dont give more space to the boardPanel. 
Why is this happening ? Doest it have to do with the bounds of the panels ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial on GridBagLayout: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html . Also see the code below and screenshot. The anchor field positions the component at the first line. The weightx field gives more space to the columns for boardPanel. The ipady field specifies how much to add to the height of the component. Here, boardPanel gets most of the width and all of the height. The otherPanel panel gets half of the height.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridExample {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel boardPanel, otherPanel;

    public GridExample(){
        mainFrame = new JFrame();
        mainFrame.setSize(600,400);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
                System.exit(0);
            }        
        });    

        boardPanel = new JPanel();
        boardPanel.add(new JLabel("board panel"));
        boardPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        otherPanel = new JPanel();
        otherPanel.add(new JLabel("other panel"));
        otherPanel.setBackground(Color.green);

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.75;
        c.ipady = 400;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        mainFrame.add(boardPanel, c);

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.25;
        c.ipady = 200;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;    
        mainFrame.add(otherPanel, c);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        GridExample  swingContainerDemo = new GridExample();  
    }
}
```

[image]